# How to change the Kafka.properties file in Kafka cluster broker through helm operator

Tags: kubernetes-helm, confluent-platform

We have setup the Kafka cluster based on the confluent Kafka operator and successfully deployed. In running cluster , if we want to modify some property parameters , how we can change bu using helm command .

Example : kafka broker , we deployed based on the following helm command .

```
helm upgrade --install \
  kafka \
  ./confluent-operator \
  --values my-values.yaml \
  --namespace koperator \
  --set kafka.enabled=true
```

parameters as in below
[image]

Example,
Suppose I want to change on parameter  from `auto.create.topics.enable=false`
to `auto.create.topics.enable=true` where I should change ?

1. should we created custom docker image ?
2. Manually should be updated ?
3. my-values.yaml ?

I tried to change, but not getting updated.

```
 helm upgrade --install \
    kafka \
    ./confluent-operator \
    --values my-values.yaml \
    --namespace koperator \
    --set kafka.enabled=true \
    --set auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this . We can actually  override the auto.create.topics.enable setting by modifying your global configuration file.

It describes how to set it and apply the changes, eg:

```
kafka: 
  configOverrides: 
    server: 
      - auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

You can find this documented in more detail at https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-configure.html#ak-and-zk-configuration-overrides